# PHPUnit and Selenium Webdriver - get different test classes to run concurrently

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I'm using PHPUnit and Selenium 2 Webdriver to automate tests for my web application.

I have several test classes which are at the moment running one after the other. However, I think that they could easily run in parallel in separate instances of the browser, which would significantly reduce the amount of time taken to test the application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it by myself but I found ParaTest which is:

> a tool that sits on top of PHPUnit and allows you to run tests in
>   parallel without the use of extensions.

Take a look on their [site](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/parallel-testing-for-phpunit-with-paratest/) for detailed information.

Altrnatively parallel-phpunit from this [page](https://github.com/verkkokauppacom/parallel-phpunit)

The other approach is described by the folks from sauce labs  [here](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/12/a-brief-history-in-progress-of-running-tests-in-parallel-with-phpunit/) but you would need to check if it's still valid.